# Gluon GListen ToggleButton too wide

Tags: javafx, gluon

The ToggleButton when rendered under Gluon GListen seems to be at least 50px wide, normal ToggleButtons do not show that behavior and are rendered much narrower. I cannot find which CSS to use to make GLuon's narrower as well... Setting the padding to 0 only works on the height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from `-fx-padding`, there is also a minimum width specified for all buttons. You can specify `-fx-min-width` with a value of 0 to let the button shrink to the width of its content:

```
.toggle-button {
    -fx-min-width: 0;
}
```